# Can you check whether the answer to the following question relating to python pickle/unpickle is correct or not-

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

Question-
A binary file “Book.dat” has structure [BookNo, Book_Name, Author, Price].
i. Write a user defined function CreateFile() to input data for a record and add to Book.dat .
ii. Write a function CountRec(Author) in Python which accepts the Author name as parameter and count and return number of books by the given Author are stored in the binary file “Book.dat”

Answer-

```
import pickle
def createFile():
  fobj=open("Book.dat","ab")
  BookNo=int(input("Book Number : "))
  Book_name=input("Name :")
  Author = input("Author: ")
  Price = int(input("Price : "))
  rec=[BookNo,Book_name,Author,Price]
  pickle.dump(rec,fobj)
  fobj.close()

def CountRec(Author):
  fobj=open("Book.dat","rb")
  num = 0
  try:
    while True:
      rec=pickle.load(fobj)
      if Author==rec[2]:
        num = num + 1
  except:
    fobj.close()
  return num
```

My comments-
If the binary file "Book.dat" has multiple records of the form [BookNo,Book_name,Author,Price] then the line
rec=pickle.load(fobj)
should load the entire file into the rec object and we cannot compare the author name to rec[2].
So the above answer should be incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this problem locally? If yes, what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct as the load will load only one object at a time.